# GIGABYTE-H81M-HD3 4 RAM modules (4 x 4GB) boot issue

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, ddr3

I have GIGABYTE-H81M-HD3 and ran with 2 RAM modules (2 x 4 GB). Now I have bought another two, but after pluging in the PC doesn't boot. It starts, run for a while and turn off and after few second it try to ran again.

I supposse that it could be because another two RAM slots are expansion and there is something to set up.

RAM are compatible, I have tried to run one of the older and one new in pair and system runs. Both new run too well. Problem is when I use slots DDR3_3 a DDR3_4.

Any suggestion or advice?

Thank you in advance,
O.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is tricky, and memory kits are trickier.   Especially if you have one RAM stick that is bad; you have to return both anyway.

Chances are, that's your situation.  The best way to test for bad RAM is to go through valid configurations of RAM for the motherboard with as few sticks as possible to see if you can recreate the problem and narrow it down to only one stick.  If this happens, you have a bad stick.

It's important to note that if you have an overclock, you should reduce your clockspeed back to stock settings before you install new RAM.  This is because new RAM means fiddling with new RAM timings and it also means that your overclock has a new factor in its stability; reducing to stock speeds eliminates issues with the OC from affecting your testing.